# How to remove all numbers and all text from string by using javascript replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Hot to remove all number and all text from stringby using javascript `replace` javascript ?

https://jsfiddle.net/jgcsw41s/

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "123aBcD#$%"; 
    var res = str.replace("1-9,a-z,A-Z", "");
    alert(res);
}
</script>
```

When i tested my code it's not replace.

How can i do that ?

Comment: [*replace*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.replace) takes either a string or regular expression. You've provided a string, so you're trying to match the string literal "1-9,a-z,A-Z".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try, regex.

```
str.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
```

---

1. [a-zA-Z0-9] match a single character present in the list below
2. a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
3. A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
4. 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
5. g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Or as Rob mentioned (Thanks Rob).

```
str.replace(/\w/g, '')
```

will do too.

Comment: `/\w/g` seems a lot shorter. ;-)

Comment: Yes, but that will also replace underscores. So `/[a-z\d]/i` could work.

Comment: `(?!_)\w` can be used.